# How to grab the hidden field stripeToken from a view to a model on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, stripe-payments

I have the following Stripe script on a view (send.php) which return through a post method a hidden field stripeToken. How do I grab that hidden field stripeToken into a model (sendForm)? Thanks

```
<form method="post">
 <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-name="TEST"
          data-description="testing"
          data-amount="2000"
          data-locale="auto">
 </script>
</form>
```

How do I grab stripeToken from the model (sendForm)?

```
//from the SendForm model    
$token  = $_POST['stripeToken']; // It is not working
```

Comment: Where is the stripeToken markup?

Comment: I know nothing about Yii2, but according to a quick Google search, it looks like `$token = $request->post('stripeToken');` may do the trick? (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html#request-parameters)

Comment: Thanks for your anwer. $request = Yii::$app->request; $token = $request->post('stripeToken');